# Сan't automatically connect to RDS via the script on EC2?

Tags: mysql, linux, amazon-web-services

Im use terraform to create infrastr. in AWS. I'm using script on ec2 userdata, that connects to rds.But this script doesn`t work.

```
#! /bin/bash 
yum update -y
yum install -y httpd
service httpd start
usermod -a -G apache centos
chown -R centos:apache /var/www
yum install -y mysql php php-mysql
systemctl enable httpd.service
cd /var/www/html/
echo "[mysql]" > ~/.my.cnf
echo "user = myuser" >> ~/.my.cnf
echo "password = passworddata" >> ~/.my.cnf
chmod 600 ~/.my.cnf   
cd database/
mysql -h db_server_address < script.sql
systemctl restart httpd.service
```

/var/log/cloud-init-output.log
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'10.0.1.91' (using password: NO)

Application cannot connect to the database because there is no schema created.
But, when I do it manually into the instance everything works fine.I understand that script is not perfect, but what's the problem,why the script don`t take credentials from ~/.my.cnf?

Comment: You are putting your credentials in a readable file in /var/www/html where they are accessible to anyone on the internet.

Comment: @stark-- I know. Thats just for myself.

Comment: Please expand on "doesn`t work". What is the specific behavior you are seeing? How does it differ from the expected behavior? Are there any errors in the cloud-init logs on the server that would give a clue as to the issue? You mention something about being unable to connect to an RDS database, so I assume there are some DB connection error messages you are seeing somewhere?

Comment: @MarkB--sorry i forgot to add logs.
/var/log/cloud-init-output.log ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'10.0.1.91' (using password: NO).                                                                           I expected the script takes the credentials from ~/.my.cnf and automatically import the SQL File into the RDS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably env variables are not loaded to load data from /root, use:

```
mysql --defaults-file=~/.my.cnf -h db_server_address < script.sql
```